# Empty request body on jQuery JSON ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, django, heroku

Server: Django 1.4 running on Heroku. All requests are HTTPS.

My ajax calls look like this:

```
var data = {
  username: form.find('input[name="username"]').val(),
  email: form.find('input[name="email"]').val()
};
$.ajax({
  url: '/register',
  type: 'POST',
  data: JSON.stringify(data),
  contentType: 'application/json',
  dataType: 'text',
  headers: {
    'X-CSRFToken': $.cookie('csrftoken')
  }
});
```

Occasionally, parsing the request body on the server fails because `request.body` is completely empty. It's fairly rare, but since I use this idiom on many pages, I see it a few times each week. Probably about 2-5% of these requests.

The CSRF token header is there along with the rest, so it appears that only the body itself is missing. In a recent request, I noticed a `CONTENT_LENGTH 2` header as well, which would be too short to contain the real request data. I wonder where that got added.

I would love some help debugging this. I can't see any way for the `JSON.stringify` call to return the empty string. Is that reasonable? If so, then it has to be that the request body is either getting stripped off in-flight, or something in my Django application is doing it.

Any help debugging or ideas on how to reproduce this would be most welcome.

Comment: You have error in javascript missing `)` after second val

Answer (score 0):

The only time I've seen similar behavior is when I request data and on the retrieving end I interpret the data as the wrong type eg. in my case jQuery expects JSON but XML was sent then I get empty data. I then have to set jQuery to explicitly interpret the data as xml. Could it be the case for you?

Comment: I believe the dataType: 'text' option in the $.ajax call prevents jQuery from doing any interpretation, so this shouldn't apply.